# Perl 6: automated testing of terminal-based programs

Tags: testing, terminal, interactive, raku

How could I automate interactions with command line programs that expose a text terminal interface with Perl 6 for testing purposes?

Comment: Do you mean using Perl 6 to test programs console programs?

Comment: Testing (`use Test`) a Perl 6 module which provides a method with user interaction.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use Perl 6 to automate execution or testing of console applications, I think you're going to use [NativeCall](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall) to interact with the [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) library. Once expect is installed, `man libexpect` will show its API documentation, though the way of accessing the documentation (such as the manpage name) may differ per package distribution.

Expect has APIs to launch a program, wait for text to appear on the (emulated) console (to "expect" text), and send text to the console (to emulate typing). The most common use case is to automate programs which require password input. Expect is often scripted--it is an interpreter--but there's no reason not to use it from a higher level programming language.

**Edit:** I somewhat answered the wrong question. The OP is interested in testing Perl 6 modules with Perl 6. That said, using expect to launch a second Perl 6 interpreter which uses the module is still the strongest, most strict way to test the application. You don't need to know what type of terminal library the module uses, because expect should be compatible with nearly all of them. You can send text to the STDIN pipe of a subprocess, but that's not as strong as the subprocess (console) communication you can get from expect. I don't know if there's a way to hijack whichever terminal library the module uses and communicate with it directly.

Comment: @raiph It's primarily an automation tool, to drive console applications. But it should still be helpful for testing, if you want to use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a plain interface, you could just [`run`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/run) the program and collect output. The currently-experimental [`Testo` module](https://modules.perl6.org/repo/Testo) has `is-run` routine. You could use that directly, or if experimental status is bothersome, copy the [guts of it](https://github.com/zoffixznet/perl6-Testo/blob/f27f37267baed7e3c0d58f74743ada5e392d5370/lib/Testo/Test.pm6#L67-L102) into your own helper routine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sparrow6 Task Check Language](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/taskchecks.md) - Perl6 based DSL to verify text output. I've done a lot terminal apps testing using it.